# Custom Formatter From Library

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I understand that to use a custom reporter one needs to `--format
fully.qualified.name.of.MyFormatter`. However I have a custom formatter that is inside a jar. How do I use it? Is there a hidden `CucumberOptions` I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) answers your question.

You first obtain the full path to your jar then you supply that path to --format.